# ASP.NET MVC 2 : How to call DisplayFor for each item in a collection?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-2

I have property in my model which is a collection type (List). I'd like to call for each item in this collection `Html.DisplayFor` or `Html.EditorFor`. How can I do this ?

EDIT It's not a strong-typed view. It's a templated view. There is only ViewData.ModelMetadata.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478378/using-html-editorfor-with-an-ienumerablet

Answer (score 8):

Can you try

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.MyCollection) { %>
    <%= html.EditorFor(m=>item) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, in your view?

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.MyCollection) { %>
    <%= html.EditorFor... %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

See also [using Html.EditorFor with an IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478378/using-html-editorfor-with-an-ienumerablet)

Comment: But How to do this in a temple view. There is no Model.items. Just ViewData.ModelMetadata..

Comment: If your collection is in a ViewData item, it would be something like `foreach(MyItemType item in (IEnumerable<MyItemType>)ViewData["MyCollection"])`

Comment: yes but the MyItemType could be anything.. therefor I'm trying to create template.. 

Something like here http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2009/08/15/creating-a-html.displayformany-helper-for-mvc-2.aspx but I don't get the expression stuff :-(

Comment: Ah, you trapped me. I didn't know that's what you wanted. You can build stuff like this but it's not for the faint of heart. He's using functors and expression trees in his `DisplayForMany`. Even if you use his function, you will still be required to specify your type for the generic method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just add a 'SelectedItem' property to your model:

```
public class YourModel
{

public IEnumberable<Item> YourCollection
{
get;
}


public Item SelctedItem
{
get;
set;
}


}
```

Then just assign each item in the list to the selctedItem property:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.YourCollection) { %>   

Model.SelctedItem = item;

<%= html.EditorFor(SelctedItem) %>   
    ...   
<% } %>
```