# Repopulating certain property values if ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have the following action method (partial code):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("Create", editGrantApplicationViewModel);
   }

   return View("Index");
}
```

`EditGrantApplicationViewModel` looks like this (partial code):

```
public class EditGrantApplicationViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Title> Titles { get; set; }
   public int TitleId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
   public int BankId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<AccountType> AccountTypes { get; set; }
   public int AccountTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

When this `Create` view is requested for the first time I would populate `Titles` in my service layer and just return an instance of `EditGrantApplicationViewModel` like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel = grantApplicationService.CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel();

   return View(editGrantApplicationViewModel);
}
```

The `CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel` in my service layer:

```
public EditGrantApplicationViewModel CreateEditGrantApplicationViewModel()
{
   EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel = new EditGrantApplicationViewModel
   {
      Titles = titleRepository
         .GetAll()
         .Where(x => x.Active)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
   };

   return editGrantApplicationViewModel;
}
```

When I click the submit button it will go into the post action `Create` method.  It receives an `editGrantApplicationViewModel` parameter of type `EditGrantApplicationViewModel`.  Why is the Titles property set to null?  I thought it would retain it values?

Now lets say that there is an error, `ModelState.IsValid` is false.  So this means that I am going to have to repopulate the `Titles` property.  Given the property values that have been set in the form in `editGrantApplicationViewModel`, how would I populate the Titles property now?  I'm assuming that I would need to have another method in my service layers that populates it?  What is the best way to do this?

Any source code would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 2011-04-11**

On my view I have 3 dropdowns.  Titles, banks, and account types.  This is why I have 3 lists in my view model.  I have a service class for each to handle inserts, updates, and getting items.  For example, in my bank service class I would have Insert, Update, GetAll, GetById, etc methods relating to bank.  I would have similar in the title and account type services.

This is how I currently have it in my controller class:

```
private IGrantApplicationService grantApplicationService;
private ITitleService titleService;
private IBankService bankService;
private IAccountTypeService accountTypeService;

public GrantApplicationController(IGrantApplicationService grantApplicationService, ITitleService titleService, IBankService bankService, IAccountTypeService accountTypeService)
{
   this.grantApplicationService = grantApplicationService;
   this.titleService = titleService;
   this.bankService = bankService;
   this.accountTypeService = accountTypeService;
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
   EditGrantApplicationViewModel editGrantApplicationViewModel = new EditGrantApplicationViewModel
   {
      // Populate the dropdown lists
      Titles = titleService
         .GetAll()
         .Where(x => x.Active)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name),
      Banks = bankService
         .GetAll()
         .Where(x => x.Active)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name),
      AccountTypes = accountTypeService
         .GetAll()
         .Where(x => x.Active)
         .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
   };

   return View(editGrantApplicationViewModel);
}
```

We spoke a while back, you said that it is preferable to have one service for a controller.  In my case I need to populate 3 lists from 3 different database tables.  Can you please provide some code as to how you would have done it.  If more details is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service layer shouldn't return view models, it should work with models. So have your service layer return those titles:

```
public IEnumerable<Title> GetTitles()
{
    return titleRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.Active)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    };
}
```

and then leave the responsibility of instantiating the view model to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new EditGrantApplicationViewModel 
    {
        Titles = grantApplicationService.GetTitles()
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EditGrantApplicationViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Reload the Titles as we are redisplaying the same view
        // and they were not part of the view model that was submitted
        model.Titles = grantApplicationService.GetTitles();
        return View("Create", model);
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: @Darin: The other day you mentioned aggregation, what did you mean by that?  What happens now if I need a AccountTypes list to be populated?  I have a service method for both AccountTypeService.GetAll and TitlesService.GetAll.  Should I  duplicate these 2 methods in my grantApplicationService?  It sounds uneccessary to me.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, it's difficult to answer such question without knowing more details about your scenario. Is there any relationship between those `Account` and `Title` entities? What justified your choice to have two service classes: `AccountTypeService` and `TitlesService`? I have the impression that you are duplicating your repositories.

Comment: @Darin: I've updated my post, and added an update section. Please let me know if I need to provide more code.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, how about writing a service method which returns some model containing 3 collection properties: Titles, Banks and AccountTypes. Then setup a mapping between the model returned by the service method and the view model in your controller.

Comment: @Darin: The other issue that I am having is when ModelState.IsValid is false then my 3 lists are null, meaning it will need to be repopulated.  Given the view model that already contains the form values, how and where would I need to repopulate these lists (from your answer above)?  If you can provide some code on this then it will be appreciated.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, the view model that is passed to the POST action **does not contain** those values. They are not part of the HTML form so they are never passed. So if the modelstate is not valid you need to repopulate them: look at my answer how the Titles property is fetched.

Comment: @Darin: So you would advise that I have an additional GetTitles in my grantApplicationService even though my TitlesService also has a GetTitles method?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, what I advice is that you have a single service (call it whatever) which aggregates multiple repositories for each entity containing CRUD operations. This service will contain a method as explained in my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since mvc is stateless (for the most part as you can use TempData and session to maintain some state).  After the initial request and display the titles property is essentially lost.

To get the `Titles` to be built back up again you need to display those values somehow on the form so the `ModelBinder` can rehydrate your `EditGrantApplicationViewModel`

You most likely will need to do something like this:

```
<% foreach(Title title in Model.Titles { %>
  <%: Html.HIddenFor(m => title) %>
<% } %>
```

*note my syntax might be a bit off since I don't have visual studio on my machine.*

Also I am not sure how the ModelBinder will handle your `IEnumberable<T>` you might have to change that to `List<T>` so the ModelBinder can build up the type correctly.

Additional information on how to bind to your `Titles` list.

1. [Post from Phil Haack about Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
2. [A slightly smiler question about mvc and `IEnumerable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478378/using-html-editorfor-with-an-ienumerablet)

Comment: In this controller's constructor I pass an IGrantApplicationService instance via constructor injection.  I guess I can pass an ITitleService instance as well, but I am trying to only pass the application service to the respective controller.  Hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Brendan, I misread the question, it appears the `Titles` is used for a drop down list and the SelectedTitle is the required field.  You will either need to persist the information on the form somehow, or as you say on invalid model state use the ITitleService to repopulate the Titles on error.