# EditorFor + foreach + complex type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Poll
{
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; } 
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    private int _amount = 0;
    public int Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; }
    }
}
```

And I need to make an Editor View.
If I try this:

```
@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)   
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => answer)
}
```

It shows everything for editing, but doesnt save changes. Controller recieves poll.Answers = null

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a very similar situation.

Comment: @JoFlash, I solved it with someyhing like this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are bypassing the advanced ID/Name generation that editors do. Since you are rendering each editor separately without any context/scope metadata, the editor renderer simply renders itself as if the model passed to it were the top-level model.

Check this question for more info:

[using Html.EditorFor with an IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478378/using-html-editorfor-with-an-ienumerablet)

Comment: Tried following that, but it didn't help.